# Monthly data switches to daily when plotted

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with values presented on **monthly** basis (dates shown as 11/01/2019, 12/01/2019, ...). That table is linked to my **daily** date table (marked as so). I have created a measure, which essentially computes the growth rate and looks something like that:

```
visitor_gr = SUM('master_s'[visitors]) / CALCULATE( SUM('master_s'[visitors]) ,
                   SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('master_dates'[dates])) -1
```

Now, the problem arises when I try to build a line chart. Instead of plotting month over month growth rates, daily ones are plotted and since I have no daily values, this yields 'infinity'

For some reason, I have noticed that when I delete "-1" and tabulate my data, it looks what it should be. When plotted, it still does not show anything.

I would greatly appreciate you help on this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by applying a filter on the dates so that only the 1st of the month is displayed:

```
Ind = IF(Day('master_dates'[dates])=1,1,0)
```

You can apply a filter on the chart using the Calculated column "Ind" restricting its value to 1. You can also use the `ALL` function to make sure that the applied filter does not impact your measure calculation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, @CR7SMS! It worked like charm! 

I may be wrong on this, but is this a walk-around method? Was I doing something wrong in general or should have structured my data table in a different way?

Comment: In a general scenario, you should have used the month variable in the calculation instead of dates. That would have prevented this particular issue. But your individual requirements might require the calculation at a date level, in which case I don't see a better way to do it.